# I want to draw a single graph using python with two columns

Tags: python, graph

I want to draw a  single graph using python with two columns excel sheet and use an excel sheet

Answer (score 1):

You can use [pandas.read_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) and then use the [plotting functions](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/visualization.html).